# Where are mathematics jobs advertised if not on mathjobs (e.g. in Europe and elsewhere)?

Tags: career, mathjobs

My impression is that in the US, there is a canonical place for finding math jobs, namely mathjobs.org. For those of us who live and apply for jobs elsewhere, life is more complicated, and searching for advertised academic mathematics jobs for example in Europe can be a real hassle, with loads of different sites, different systems, and some jobs apparently advertised only on the web page of the hiring institution, or one some obscure mailing list.

So, where are academic math jobs advertised when they for some reason are not or cannot be on mathjobs.org? Of course I know of a few such places, but I am sure there must be many more.

All answers welcome, this would help me and probably many others.

Edit : All answers are 10 years old. Some of them might not be working. Any new answers (or corrections to old answers) would be useful.

Answer (score 35):

Actually, the canonical place for finding math jobs in the US is the [AMS Employment Information](http://eims.ams.org/search/) page.  This is much older than MathJobs.org, and I still think notably more complete for more obscure jobs (and actually has quite a few foreign jobs), though MathJobs.org adoption is moving fast.

**EDIT:** As noted below, in the time since this answer was written, EIMS is being discontinued, and essentially replaced with MathJobs.

Comment: The MAA has added http://www.mathclassifieds.org  Unlike the AMS sites which are mostly geared towards phds, it tries to gather math jobs for all educational levels. 

Comment: Note that http://www.ams.org/profession/employment-services/employment-services now reports "The Employment Information in the Mathematical Sciences (EIMS) job ad service was discontinued on December 31, 2019. Please use mathjobs.org or The Notices to place or view job ads."  So that is a change.

Answer (score 31):

The European Mathematical Society has [this list](http://www.euro-math-soc.eu/national_advertisements.html) of national job advertisements on its site.

Answer (score 23):

http://www.jobs.ac.uk/jobs/mathematics

Not complete, but occasionally useful.

Comment: I'd say it's a lot more than "occasionally useful" if you're looking for jobs in the UK.  My impression is that for several years now, very nearly every UK mathematics job has been advertised on jobs.ac.uk.  They also have a mailing list you can subscribe to.  

Comment: I agree with Tom, I've always found jobs.ac.uk pretty much complete, the only exceptions being obscure Oxbridge fellowships.  These are advertised in the Oxford Gazette and Cambridge Reporter (though good luck finding your way around their appalling websites!).

Answer (score 20):

There is the Mathematics Jobs Wiki:

http://notable.math.ucdavis.edu/wiki/Mathematics_Jobs_Wiki

It is a wiki, so what is listed there is dependent on people bothering to put stuff up.  It is trying to be international in scope -- in fact, the only jobs that seem to be listed on it at the moment are from Germany.

Also, for Canada: http://www.cms.math.ca/Employment/

Answer (score 19):

For the nordic countries, there's http://www.maths.lth.se/nordic

Answer (score 14):

The math jobs wiki has been updated to list a lot of jobs in the US and Canada.  Even before it was updated, it had a fairly complete collection of links to jobs pages at the bottom.  It had every link listed here, and others.

Comment: the math jobs wiki seems to have been down for a while now. Is this permanent or will it come back online at some point?

Comment: I will put it back up soon.

Answer (score 13):

Germany (and Europe in general): http://www.academics.de/

Answer (score 13):

[http://www.math-jobs.com/](http://math-jobs.com) has quite some European jobs available.

Answer (score 13):

In Australian and New Zealand, go to http://www.austms.org.au/Jobs/
For more statistical jobs, look at http://www.statsci.org/jobs

Answer (score 13):

For jobs in France, the one site you need is [Opération Postes](http://postes.smai.emath.fr/).

Answer (score 9):

Another site for jobs in the UK & Ireland is http://www.lms.ac.uk/jobs/index.html

Jobs at Oxford and Cambridge are often advertised in the Oxford Gazette http://www.ox.ac.uk/gazette/ and the Cambridge reporter http://www.admin.cam.ac.uk/reporter/

Comment: The LMS links are now http://www.lms.ac.uk/careers/uk-jobs-mathematics and http://www.lms.ac.uk/careers/international-jobs-mathematics

Answer (score 7):

International: myScience.cc http://www.myscience.cc/jobs_and_careers?ctrl=1&d=Mathematics

Germany: myScience.de http://www.myscience.de/jobs_and_careers?ctrl=1&d=Mathematics

Switzerland: myScience.ch http://www.myscience.ch/jobs_and_careers?ctrl=1&d=Mathematics