# Question about reference letters on mathjobs

Tags: mathjobs

I have a mechanical question about the mathjobs interface (I believe this is not off -topic since there is a correct answer and this answer would remove uncertainty for other mathematicians in future job cycles). If I list a reference letter in my application to a position, but the reference letter is submitted after the formal deadline (or at least after I submit the application), will that reference letter be automatically added to my dossier at the university in question or do I have to re-submit all of my materials?

Comment: You are misled in thinking that this question is on-topic here. I suggest you try Academia at SE, where such questions may receive a better welcome. .

Comment: In the past there have been questions such as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/952/where-are-mathematics-jobs-advertised-if-not-on-mathjobs-e-g-in-europe-and-els?rq=1 (with 72 upvotes... presumably more members of the community benefited from that than a question about derived artin stacks).

Comment: I believe the answer is Yes: when you submit your application, you list the letters that should be included. But I have not been on the other side of hiring. You are not the only one who is made nervous by issues like this. @LoïcTeyssier: Seven years ago, such questions were certainly on-topic, but I agree that the scope of MO has changed. I have started https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3019/ to provide a place to discuss whether mathjobs questions are on-topic at MO.

Comment: I cannot(for lack of rep) and probably should not participate in that discussion, but I would just say that probably a senior mathematician can give a correct, complete answer in a few lines and that this does concern research level mathematicians.

Comment: Before, it'd have been on-topic alright, but a dedicated site for academical questions now exists, and I believe that makes all the difference. So, please, don't derived-artin-stacks me as I was merely pointing out a place where the question could be on-topic: I never said anything on the intrinsic interest or helpfulness of the OP. Each post in the right forum, et les vaches seront bien gardées ;)

Comment: In my experience there is not a "dossier at the university" independent of what's on mathjobs. Whenever they must make a decision, typical search committee members will just log into mathjobs and look at what's there at the time. What you might do if a letter arrives late, is send the search committee chair a brief email to make sure it's noticed.

Comment: Manually moved to: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79067/question-about-reference-letters-on-mathjobs as there are likely many qualified people to answer on this site... I'll leave this comment

Comment: If you click on the "applied" link on the posting for a job you have applied for you can see your application, and in particular the recommendation letters that are being used. I'd recommend doing this anyway to check that you have the right cover letter, etc.

Comment: Yes, your letter is automatically added to your mathjobs file once submitted and so yes, your letter will probably get seen if your file is being seriously considered by the committee.  (Unless of course it arrives way too late.)